# Several online media players don't work in Firefox but they do in Chrome

Tags: 13.04, firefox, google-chrome

I have noticed that I have not been able to play audio or video from a few different players in Firefox for a while, namely videos from the [Canal + Zapping website](http://www.canalplus.fr/c-infos-documentaires/pid1830-c-zapping.html) and music from the [Free Music Archive website](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Johnny_Haway/); however, most other websites, like Youtube, Dailymotion and Soundcloud, work perfectly in Firefox.

Also, this problem does not exist in Google Chrome.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Firefox 22.0 with *proposed* and *backport* updates, as well as `ubuntu-restricted-extras 57` installed.

Cheers

Comment: Could some extension be to blame? Maybe some script that needs to function is being blocked? http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Johnny_Haway/Race_Soul/El_sky_lo_try plays for me in Firefox 23 (beta).

Comment: Thanks vasa1, it was actually the add-on HTTPS Everywhere that was the culprit. I could listen to the Free Music Archive after disabling it.
The Zapping website ended up working fine after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the add-on [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) that was the culprit. I could listen to the Free Music Archive after disabling it.

The Zapping website ended up working fine after a while, without any particular action.

I might add that streams using mp4, like [this one](http://www.4eb.org.au/ondemand), because of [licensing issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) (they will support it when a third-party decoder is available).